# Creating new Objects in JPQL returns only one object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a JPA Entity with a large number of fields and millions of records. For a report, I need only some of the fields. So I want to create an Object with the essential fields due to resource constraints. I tried to create a list of new objects in JPQL. It gives only one object as a result, where multiple objects are expected.

```
String j;
    j = "select new lk.gov.health.phsp.pojcs.ClientEncounterComponentBasicDataToQuery("
            + "f.name, "
            + "f.code, "
            + "f.item.code, "
            + "f.shortTextValue, "
            + "f.integerNumberValue, "
            + "f.longNumberValue, "
            + "f.realNumberValue, "
            + "f.booleanValue, "
            + "f.dateValue, "
            + "f.itemValue.code"
            + ") ";

    j += " from ClientEncounterComponentItem f "
            + " where f.retired=false "
            + " and f.encounter.id=:eid";
    Map m = new HashMap();
    m.put("eid", endId);
```

The EBJ is as follows.

```
public List<Object> findObjects(String jpql, Map<String, Object> parameters, TemporalType tt) {
    TypedQuery<Object> qry = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql, Object.class);
    Set s = parameters.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        Object pVal = m.getValue();
        String pPara = (String) m.getKey();
        if (pVal instanceof Date) {
            Date pDate = (Date) pVal;
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pDate, TemporalType.DATE);
        } else {
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pVal);
        }
    }
    try {
        return qry.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using EclipseLink as the persistence provider.

Comment: Did you check the exact query executed in console ? Please add it also. and `List<Object>` contains only one object right ?

Comment: Yes. I printed the size property, it comes as one always.

Comment: And the SQL issued? Why do you think the ClientEncounterComponentItem table has more than one row where retired=false for the encounter.id value you specified? Do any of these f.xxx.yyy involve relationships that might filter your expected results because they use inner joins?

Comment: You are correct. It is because there was only one row. Thank you so much. I can't accept it as an answer as it is a comment.